# order by Table Number Field

Tags: craft3, relations, table-field

```
% set entriesList = craft.entries.section('parks').relatedTo(entry.Line.one()).all %}
    {% if entriesList|length %}
    <div id="found-in" class="park">
        <ul>
            {% for entry in entriesList %}
            <li><a class="underline" href="{{entry.url}}">{{entry.title}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Every Element has a Table where a Number is set
I want to order it by the Number. How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[orderBy()](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#orderby) should do the trick.
The docs show following syntax: `.orderBy('elements.dateCreated asc')`

Maybe something like:

```
{% set entriesList = craft.entries.section('parks')
   .relatedTo(entry.Line.one())
   .orderBy('elements.tableName.row(n).columnName asc')
   .all
%}
```

Comment: Nope. Just a Error. :/

Comment: Have you replaced tableName, n and columName with your specific details? Maybe use [] instaed of () for the row "elements.tableName.row[n].columnName"?

Comment: Another possible solution: .orderBy('elements.tableFieldName[n] asc') where n = row number

Comment: tableName and columnName - Yes but what is the n for? I thought near.

Comment: .orderBy('elements.parkInfo.row(n).person asc')

Comment: here is the error i get Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`personen`) `subquery`
INNER JOIN `entries` `entries` ON `entries`.`id` = `subq' at line 13
)

Comment: n = row number. You have "person" in the orderBy statement but "personen" in the error. Anyway, ist is possible that "row" didn't work. Did you test my second suggestion?

Comment: Yes i tried both. I found a solution with the supersort Plug-In and ('natsort') option for the Title - because the Title has the same Number too. Not the best Method i think but it work. Anyway, thanks for the help.